Converting Domain User account to Local User account
I am attempting to convert several Domain user accounts to Local user accounts as it has become necessary to remove those assets from our domain. I want to make sure that the user accounts are the same so the employees do not lose productivity. Is there some way I can do this?
I already tested ForensIT and PCMover and both work but I want to minimize cost

There is no conversion between AD user and local user. You can not store local users in Active Directory domain controller. You should find a convenient server and with powershell script you can use get-ADUser to  find the properties and using new-Localuser cmdlet create the the local user on the server that you have determined using the properties applicable to new-localuser cmdlet.
